# Logit function and marginal effects

Tags: mlogit, marginal-effects, logits, r-marginaleffects

I have 2 approaches to calculate my marginal effects.

The first model is the following

```
model1 <- 
  feglm(
    FTAs ~ 
      log(dist) +
      log(gdp_d) +
     ...,
   
    family = binomial(link = "logit"),
    data = data
  )
```

And I calculate the marginal effects via

```
model1_marginaleffects <- 
  slopes(
    model1
  )
summary(model1_marginaleffects)
```

My second approach was the following which automatically calculates the marginal effects.

```
model2 <- 
  logitmfx(
    FTAs ~ 
      log(dist) +
      log(gdp_d) +
      
    
    data = data
    
  )

print(logitmfx_model3)
```

Does anyone know where the difference is coming from? The signs (+/-) are the same but the values totally differ. Do the functions take another baseline to calculate the marginal effects. If yes, what is the difference?

I looked into the documentations: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/marginaleffects/marginaleffects.pdf as well as https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mfx/mfx.pdf, but I do not understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `marginaleffects` computes the "average marginal effect (or slope)", whereas `logitmfx` computes the "marginal effect (or slope) at the mean".

Those are distinct quantities. Here is a nice tutorial: https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2022/05/20/marginalia/

Note that you can easily compute both quantities with the `marginaleffects` package. The discrepancy you observe is simply because the *defaults* differ, and not because `marginaleffects` is incapable of replicating `logitmfx`.

Also, please consider that it is much easier to answer a question like this when it is accompanied by a minimal working example. See:

[How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)